# Showing a progress dialog while creating view for android activity

Tags: android, xamarin.android

In an android activity I have a lenghty process in building a report (view).  I would like to show a progress dialog "Building Report..Please Wait" while the view is being created.  Is it possible to start and activity (screen switch) and then show a progress dialog and then present the view?

I guess alternatively I could build the view on a background thread from the main activity while showing a progress dialog and then once the view is created I could start the next activity and present the built view.

What is the best way to handle something like this, i.e. show feedback while a complex view is being built?  The view has to be built in code, not XML, and with the iterations of the data it can be a few seconds.  I want the application to appear responsive.

Thank you.

Comment: Check this out: http://www.anddev.org/novice-tutorials-f8/imageview-with-loading-spinner-t49439.html It's an ImageView that show's a spinner until it is loaded. Not exactly what you want but it is the same principle. Enjoy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out.  I show the progress dialog and then start a background task which has the setcontentView in the RunOnUiThread element and hide the progress dialog.